# What's the substitution of Input::had() in Laravel 4?

Tags: forms, checkbox, laravel, laravel-4

I'm porting an existent L3 project into L4.

In my login view I've used `{{ Form::checkbox('remember', 'remember', Input::had('remember')) }}` to repopulate the status of remember me button.

However, in L4, Input::had is deprecated. So what's the substitution of `Input::had()`? Or there's another sexier way to repopulate status of a checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
{{ Form::checkbox('remember', 'remember', null !== Input::old('remember')) }}
```

Comment: Finally I used `null !== Input::old('remember')` instead. BTW, `Input::old()`, as a return value of function, cannot be used in `empty()`.